# Select rowid from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, count

I can't seem to find this information in other questions, even though I think it is a basic problem.

In mySQL, I'm attempting to COUNT the number of rows in column "rowid" from the one table that occurs in thousands of different schemas (therefore listing the schemas individually is impractical).

Note: some schemas do not have the table, and therefore no information.

Thanks!

**Edit**:

I attempted the script below and it kept returning:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() ...

This was on the SECOND execute function. To fix this, I manually input the result of the first sql into the second variable sql but that gave me:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in _____ on line 18 *(aka the first prepare statement)*

Here is the code. You'll see I've been playing around with it a bunch (I used a different connect method to see if that changed anything)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$db = mysql_connect(localhost,******, *******);


$sql = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Ftrans /*this is our specific table name*/'
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'rowid'";


$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); /*this is where I got the second error*/
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
   // $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $row->TABLE_SCHEMA.$row->TABLE_NAME";


 $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fp_AIRG.Ftransi";
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->execute();
 $count = $stmt2->fetchColumn();
}
mysql_close($db);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to run the same SQL query in thousands of different databases?

Comment: SenorAmor: This is what I have tried so far, which is advice I got off of a different site.

SELECT COUNT(rowid)
FROM schema..table

I get a "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.Ftrans' at line 2"

Alexis: I might be mixing up my sql language, but I have one database, in which I have thousands of Schemas, most of which have the table (say TA), which then has a specific column (rowid) that I need. The SQL would then hopefully give me back count of all rowid's in every schema.

Comment: You have used mysql_connect instead of PDO. Take another look at my example.

Comment: I changed that to see if it would make a difference. I changed it back and I still recieved the: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /__________ on line 28 (this is the $stmt2->execute(); line )

Comment: Hmm looking at  "<?phpinfo()?> and it looks like PDO support enabled: PDO driver smysql, sqlite

Comment: Try adding exception handling around the instantiation of PDO as in my updated example.

Comment: I actually think I found the problem. Looks like  FROM {$row->TABLE_SCHEMA}.{$row->TABLE_NAME}"; is not a valid expression. PHP cannot utilize database.table format. If you just put in mysql> select count(*) fp_AIRG.Ftrans; it returns RROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.Ftrans' at line 1

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your code then. The code that I posted runs fine on my server. `database.table` is how the previous info schema query is written. Please update the question to reflect current code. The code in your question could never work as it stands right now.

Comment: So problem turned out to be an ineffective version of php. It works perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'rowid'
```

Then for each record returned -

```
SELECT COUNT(rowid)
FROM {TABLE_SCHEMA}.{TABLE_NAME}
```

Here is a PHP based implementation -

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name'
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'rowid'";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(rowid) FROM `{$row->TABLE_SCHEMA}`.`{$row->TABLE_NAME}`";
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $count = $stmt2->fetchColumn();

    echo "{$row->TABLE_SCHEMA}.{$row->TABLE_NAME}: $count\n";
}
```

I have not run this so it may have some errors in it but it should get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: I ran the first query (replaced tbl_name with the correct table) and it doesn't return any records- maybe because information_schema does not work on my database?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? It has been available since 5.0.

Comment: I'm personally using workbench 5.2, but it might be possible that the server was set up in an older version, would that matter?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "version"` will return the server version. Do you get a result when you run it without the WHERE clause?

Comment: Version 5.1.30-log is what that returned and running without the where clause gives me error 1064, "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND COLUMN_NAME = 'rowid'' at line 3"

Also, thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Is this server in a replication hierarchy? Do you get the same problem when executing - `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`? This can be caused by running out of space for the temp directory.

Comment: Yes! Space was exactly the problem- but SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA worked. Not to sound extremely pathetic, but I'm not sure now how to run SELECT COUNT(rowid)
FROM {TABLE_SCHEMA}.{TABLE_NAME} on that query, assuming because that first query does not contain the rowid info.

Comment: What is your scripting language of choice? Personally I would write it in PHP. Is this something you need to do repeatedly or is it a one off?

Comment: One off for the present, but ideally I would be able to use this in the future. I'm a VERY beginner in PHP, but that would be my choice...

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely incredible! I can't tell you how much I appreciate this!!

Comment: Please remember to accept this answer if it works for you. Just click on the tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is. I have copied your last comment into your original question. Please remove the last comment and update the question explaining the problem.

Comment: Sorry! I've added my comments into my original question